# Does Array.ToArray<>() return the original array if it is the same type?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I deal with a framework on a daily basis where we sometimes provide methods that accept `IEnumerable<MyBusinessObject>` as a parameter in order to show user interfaces, perform calculations etc.

If I pass in an array of `MyBusinessObject` like so:

```
MyBusinessObject[] myArray = new MyBusinessObject { obj1, obj2, ..., objN };
frameworkClass.MyMethod(myArray);

....

public class FrameworkClass
{
    public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyBusinessObject> objs)
    {
        // Other code that uses the enumerable
        MyBusinessObject[] objectArray = objs.ToArray();            
        // More code that uses the enumerable
    }
}
```

Does the line `objs.ToArray()` simply resolve the `IEnumerable<MyBusinessObject>` back to the original array, or does it copy it to a whole new array, ready for use?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No, you will **always** get a new copy of the array, though the objects in it aren't copies, they are the same references as in the original array.

It would be very inconsistent for changes to the returned array to *sometimes* affect the source and sometimes not. `ToList` works the same way for the same reason.

---

You can check source code (as of 2015) if you need to review details: [Enumerable.ToArray](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d) which in turn creates copy of elements (optimized for `ICollection` and hence `Array[]`, but still making copy) with internal [Buffer class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f14dd065ac796f44,references).

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be another question, but I just wanted to quickly see if you know this too: does `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` call the array's `.Length` property to get a result, or does it do something horribly inefficient?

Comment: Have to bow to Mr Skeet for that one.  Personally, I bet it doesn't (IEnumerable doesn't have a Length property).  However there's a chance it does some clever reflection stuff for certain scenarios as an optimisation.  Point is, if you want a count, IEnumerable isn't appropriate - IList<T> is.

Comment: @Codesleuth: Looking at [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), the `Count` method checks if the object implements `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` (which an array does) and uses its `Count` property instead of looping through the items.

Answer (score 8):

You will get a new copy of the array **if there is one or more element in it**. For empty arrays, you might get the same array back, at least in .NET 5:

```
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(Array.Empty<string>(), Array.Empty<string>().ToArray()));
```

This returns true.

Comment: Cool find. Since you can't append to arrays this is very unlikely to ever actually matter. But still, interesting!