# Does ToArray() from an array return itself?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I just want to know if the implementation of LINQ protects the developer against performance hits when calling ToArray() from an Array.

For example,

```
var array1 = Enumerable.Range(0,short.MaxValue).ToArray(); //does the actual copy
var array2 = array1.ToArray() //is this the same object as array1?
var array3 = ((IEnumerable<int>)array2).ToArray() //what about this?
```

Do all three of these ToArray() calls have the same performance implications?

Other questions like this have addressed the general performance implications of ToArray(),

[Is it better to call ToList() or ToArray() in LINQ queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105990/is-it-better-to-call-tolist-or-toarray-in-linq-queries)

[Linq ToList/ToArray/ToDictionary performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041994/linq-tolist-toarray-todictionary-performance)

but I'm curious as to whether the implementation is "smart enough" to avoid copying elements to another array if the source is an array.

I printed all of the hash codes from array 1, 2, and 3.

```
    Console.WriteLine(array1.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine(array2.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine(array3.GetHashCode());
```

and got

`62476613
11404313
64923656`

Since the hash codes are all different does that mean that a copy operation happened all three times?

Comment: No Shortcut. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d,references

Comment: No, it always returns a new copy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092811/does-array-toarray-return-the-original-array-if-it-is-the-same-type

Comment: You've already shown, in the question, that different arrays are returned, so why are you asking the question when you've already gotten your answer?

Comment: bah... i didn't see that answer. I duplicated the question then..

Comment: @Servy I've been pestered before to show better research effort in questions

Comment: @matrixugly And rightly so.  And, in doing that research, you appear to have already found your answer.  Having already found your answer why did you post the question anyway?

Comment: @Servy isn't the purpose of SO to share helpful things you find?

Comment: This has been answered by multiple people now, so I won't, but another test you could've done is to use `Object.ReferenceEquals()`. That's not to say the items in the arrays aren't the same as the original elements. If the type of the `IEnumerable` is a value type, then they are copies, if the type is a reference type, then they are the same object, just a different pointer.

Comment: @matrixugly It's to be a repository of useful questions with useful answers.  When the information you've found is already readily apparent and accessible, duplicating it is not adding value.

Comment: @Servy OK. You asked why I posted the question when I had also posted some research on the question. Granted, it was a duplicate- I missed that.

Comment: @matrixugly - side note on referencing other posts - consider posting links directly which will auto-magically turn into titles of the post instead of "this question" text. This saves one time to figure out what questions you are linking to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does ToArray() from an array return itself?

No it doesn't. It returns a new copy of the array with each element copied to the new array.

> Do all three of these ToArray() calls have the same performance
>   implications?

The first one: `Enumerable.Range(0,short.MaxValue).ToArray();` creates an array from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Second one: `var array2 = array1.ToArray()`, It will create a new array with each element copied to `array2`, so `array1` and `array2` will have different references.

Third one: `var array3 = ((IEnumerable<int>)array2).ToArray()` is just redundant code, since the array is already `IEnumerable<int>` so casting it to it will not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Does ToArray() from an array return itself?

I will say no, beause of MSDN's own words:

> Creates an array from a IEnumerable.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx