# How can I copy a List and then convert it to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I need to make a copy of a `List` as an `array`.  I can copy the list and then convert it to an `array`, but it seems like this has an unnecessary step.  It would make more sense to me to just copy it directly into an `array`, but I do not know how. This is the version with the unnecessary step:

```
List<T> originalList = GetListOfElements<T>();
T[] copyArray = new List<T>(originalList).ToArray();
```

Is it possible to bypass the step of creating the new `List`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, `list` `ToArray` fits best with your need, since [it will return copy of the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092811/does-array-toarray-return-the-original-array-if-it-is-the-same-type) rather than the same elements (read the link). Note: only beware that depending on what is `T`, the `object` itself may not necessarily be the `copy` (such as `List<int>` is different from `List<MyClass>`).

Simply do:

```
T[] array = GetListOfElements<T>().ToArray();
```

It would have been trickier if you do **not** want to copy the elements.

Comment: @LeandroSoares the final answer, yes. but I gave necessary concept, the link, and the case to be aware of.

Comment: ToArray is not for linq.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ah yes, it is actually of `List`

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand. Does the following not work?

```
 T[] arr = GetListOfElements<T>().ToArray();
```

Comment: I need to make a copy.  I don't want the original values.

Comment: It is a copy. `ToArray` does not expose the internal array used by the list. It creates a new one.

Comment: ToArray does exactly what you want. It doesn't maintain the same memory block.